EKS unable to access Internal API within pod
I have created 2 load balancers from a Deployment file.

Internal Ingress (for internal load balamcer)
External Ingress (for external load balancer).
Now after deploying i am able to access internal api with in VPC but not from pod. for example

curl https://test-internal.test.com/systime

gives me output if i execute from outside of pod (with in same VPC).
but if do same curl call within the pod
seeing the below error
curl: (52) Empty reply from server


I have tried to do nslookup within pod it is resolving.
I have done telnet from pod to the endpoint which is connecting.
What more things do i need to check here


Usually clusters are setup so that Ingresses are not visible from within the cluster. For pod-to-pod communication Services should be used.
Also Ingresses are used for traffic routing. While load-balancing of requests may take place it is not their primary purpose, thus making your question quite hard to understand.

Yes, I agree with @TheCoolDrop, The Ingress are is at cluster level, and used to route traffic inside the cluster. For Internal communication k8s services or IP based communications. You can refer the following documentation for pod to pod communication:  https://medium.com/@extio/mastering-kubernetes-pod-to-pod-communication-a-comprehensive-guide-46832b30556b

By internal I'm assuming it's just the same as an external load balancer but you point your other services to it instead of using the k8s service name so you get proper load balancing? The traffic will therefore leave then re-enter the cluster.
Without seeing all of your ingress config etc it's hard to tell what's wrong.. but in your ingress config is the backend service correct and have you specified the correct port?
is there any kind of IP whitelist on your ingress controller or configs?

Also, are there any logs on the ingress controller that show your attempted connection? maybe there is a useful error there?

sorry for the confustion @TheCoolDrop . I mean to say i am able to access 1 URL (which is on Internal load balancer) outside of pod, but inside of pod same url is not working. i have checked telnet if any issues but i don't see any.

@MartinW No, what i can see is that if i call the url from pod i don't see call reaching to ingress thought it is reaching to the LB. But same is working fine outside pod.

We use ingress-nginx and looking at our config again our internal ingress controller doesn't create a load balancer at all, it keeps all of the traffic within the cluster. if this is useful for you I can share a few snippets from our config that are different to the external load balancer?

thanks i am able to fix the issue. Issue is at the subnet level, where my pod is residing is not able to communicate after moving to different subent it started working fine.

We use ingress-nginx and have set up an ingress controller to be internal only, we found that it does better load balancing than the round robin you get by using internal K8s service names.
Here are the snippets of ingress-nginx config that are different compared to our external controllers.
controller: 
  ingressClassResource:
    name: nginx-internal
    enabled: true
    default: false
    controllerValue: "k8s.io/ingress-nginx-internal"
  ingressClass: nginx-internal
  service:
    enabled: true
    external:
      enabled: false
    internal:
      enabled: true
      annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: 
"arn:og:our:cert:for:internal:domain"
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "http"
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb-ip"
      externalTrafficPolicy: "Cluster"

Then you can make an ingress config with this setting:
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-internal

The hostname will need to be something unique for this internal only ingress with a matching cert in AWS
No traffic outside the cluster will be able to access it
